# How to programmatically open Safari->preferences pane

Tags: objective-c, qt

I m working on safari plugin. I have added some Qt code in it. Now I want to open  "safari->preferences" pane when user clicks on QPushButton on my Qt dialog.
 If it is possible in Objective-C also, please tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got it.
Here is my solution:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate

delay 4

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"

    keystroke "," using command down

    tell window 1
        click button "Extensions" of tool bar 1
        activate "Extensions"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Using this AppleScript we can open Safari->Preferences programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know a direct api.

write an apple script and use ui scripting
to tell safari 
1) to open
2) to select the menuitem preferences (maybe even send key stroke cmd+,)

some script like:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Safari"
tell menu bar 1
tell menu bar item "Safari"
tell menu "Safari"
click menu item "Preferences..."
end tell
end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Okay..Thanks helping me Daij-Djan.

Comment: I guess there is no applescript to open Safari->Preferences

Comment: yip thats why said why I said AS with GUI Scripting: updated my answer